# Count partial matches in an ordered ArrayList using only .get() and .size()

Tags: java

This code here which returns the number of elements in the list (sorted custom array list) that have the specified prefix and suffix. It works, however it should cost log(n) + k, where k is the number of strings in the list that have that prefix. Anyways to make it more efficient and faster?

```
//StringList,custom ArrayList only contains size() and get()
public int countMatches(StringList a, String prefix, String suffix) {

    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        String temp = a.get(i);
        if (temp.startsWith(prefix) && temp.endsWith(suffix)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Update:
This is the code after the binary search has found the first prefix, the code is supposed to get rid of words that don't have the prefix. But it does not work, how comes?

```
        for (int i = low; i < high; i++) {

          if (!(prefix.compareTo(a.get(i)) > 0)) {
               high = i;
               break;
          }
        }
```

Comment: Instead of linearly searching through the list from start to end, try binary search, that is where the log(n) comes from.

Comment: The problem is how would i implement binary search with strings?

Comment: Same way you implement binary search of any sorted list/array, e.g. see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). Are you asking about the search algorithm? Or are you asking about how [`String.compareTo(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo-java.lang.String-) works?

Comment: The latter, if you could explain how i could use it here.

Answer (score 5):

If the list is sorted, you can perform a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to find the first string starting with the prefix.

Comment: Alright i've done that, the code is much better, however now i have problem with the suffix.

Comment: You should traverse the list starting from the position found by binary search until the either the list has no more elements or the string at position does not start with the prefix anymore, incrementing the counter if the string ends with the suffix.

Comment: Could you give me an example code, it would be really helpful, thanks for the previous answers.